# How to return 0 instead of blank SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the count to get the total number, but missing team 4 value.

Here is my query:

```
select 
    [Team Number], Count([Followup]) as [FeedbackNeedToBeReview]
from  
    [TICKETFEEDBACK].[db_fdd63213_8581_4bef_ae7d_004c96c5873a].[Access].[TicketFeedback Tool]
where 
    [Followup] = ''
group by 
    [Team Number]
order by 
    CAST([Team Number] as int)
```

**Output :**

[image]

If I set the condition for Team 4,Nothing is returned.

```
select 
    [Team Number], Count([Followup]) as [FeedbackNeedToBeReview]
from  
    [TICKETFEEDBACK].[db_fdd63213_8581_4bef_ae7d_004c96c5873a].[Access].[TicketFeedback Tool]
where 
    [Followup] = ''
    and [Team Number] = '4'
group by 
    [Team Number]
order by 
    CAST([Team Number] as int)
```

**Output :**

[image]

how can i return 
TeamNumber   [FeedbackNeedToBeReview]
4   0

Comment: Does Team 4 exist or already deleted?

Comment: Team 4 not exists in table.

Comment: @Tanjim Rahman: How do you know? From the output above we only know that there is no entry with an empty followup string for team 4.

Comment: First query doesn't return any rows for 4

Comment: @Tanjim Rahman: Yes, but there may still be an entry for team 4 in the table with followup <> '' or null. From the query and its output alone you cannot say there is no record for team 4 in the table.

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry I mean no entry found for condition where 
[Followup] = ''

Answer (score 4):

The correct way of this query is in my opinion as follows:

We need a table named Teams with TeamNumber field. In this table all possible teams should be existing including Team#4

Then In your query join Teams table with Feedback table. You will be using LEFT JOIN to feedbacks table

This will ensure that all rows from Teams including Team number 4 will be in the output with no feedbacks so 0 will be counted

An other option is simply using a [SQL CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/article.aspx?articleid=18) expression to simulate this as follows

```
declare @team int = 4
;with teams_cte as (
    select @team teamnumber
)
select 
    teams_cte.teamnumber, COUNT(Followup) snt
from teams_cte
left join feedbacks on feedbacks.teamnumber = teams_cte.teamnumber
where teams_cte.teamnumber = 4
group by teams_cte.teamnumber
```

which returns 4-0 as desired

Comment: You are right; when there are teams in the database, there should be a table for them. Good answer.